# Implementing a singleton class and (b)locking issues?

Tags: python, locking, singleton, blocking

I was wondering about implementing a singleton class following http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52558-the-singleton-pattern-implemented-with-python/ but was wondering about any (b)locking issues. My code is suppose to cache SQL statements and execute all cached statements using cursor.executemany(SQL, list-of-params) when a certain number of cached elements are reached or a specific execute-call is done by the user. Implementing a singleton was suppose to make it possible to cache statements application-wide, but I`m afraid I`ll run into (b)locking issues.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need a complicated recipe for a singleton, you can simply create an instance of the class and use it instead of the class itself. Why are you doing this caching, what do you think it will achieve, and what problems do you have with it? What blocking issues are you afraid of, and why would they affect your program?

Comment: if you properly handle lock/unlock logic inside singelton, there (should) be no problem.

Comment: What is more, Python modules are singletons themselves, but rarely spoken about in this way.

Answer (score 1):

By avoiding lazy initialization the blocking problem will go away. In a module where initialization of your connection to the database is occurring import the module that contains the singleton and then immediately create an instance of the singleton that is not stored in a variable.

```
#Do Database Initialization
import MySingleton
MySingleton()
#Allow threads to be created
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the module directly (as pointed out before, models are Singletons). If you create a module like:

```
# mymodule.py
from mydb import Connection
connection = Connection('host', 'port')
```

you can use the import mechanism and the `connection` instance will be the same everywhere.

```
from mymodule import connection
```

Of course, you can define a much more complex initialization of `connection` (possibly via writing your own class), but the point is that Python will only initialize the module once, and provide the same objects for every subsequent call.

I believe the Singleton (or Borg) patterns have very specific applications in Python, and for the most part you should rely on direct imports until proven otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problems unless you plan to use that Singleton instance with several threads.

Recently I've faced with some issue caused by wrongly implemented cache reloading mechanism - cache data was first cleared and then filled. This works well in single thread, but produces bugs in multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use CPython - [Global Interpreter Lock](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) should prevent blocking problems. You could also use the [Borg pattern](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/).